# How do I convert a uint256 variable to an int256 one?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, chainlink

I was trying to print `uint timeStamp` by typing `return timeStamp;` right below `return price;` from this code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract PriceConsumerV3 {

AggregatorV3Interface internal priceFeed;

/**
 * Network: Kovan
 * Aggregator: BTC/USD
 * Address: 0x6135b13325bfC4B00278B4abC5e20bbce2D6580e
 */
constructor() public {
    priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x6135b13325bfC4B00278B4abC5e20bbce2D6580e);
}

/**
 * Returns the latest price
 */
function getThePrice() public view returns (int) {
    (
        uint80 roundID, 
        int price,
        uint startedAt,
        uint timeStamp,
        uint80 answeredInRound
    ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
    return price;
    return timeStamp;
}
}
```

When I compiled the code above on the Remix Compiler, it replied:

> TypeError: Return argument type uint256 is not implicitly convertible to expected type (type of first return variable) int256. return timeStamp; ^-------^

I tend to think that I would just have to type `int256 return timeStamp` or something similar instead of `return timeStamp;` but I can't figure it out.

Feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can typecast the `uint` to `int` using this syntax:

```
return int(timeStamp);
```

*Note: This will overflow (in Solidity 0.7.x and older) or throw an exception (in Solidity 0.8+) for values between `2^255` (`int` max value) and `2^256-1` (`uint` max value). But this is most likely just a theoretical case, because timestamp is not expected to have this large value.*

---

Mind that this line is unreachable, because you're already returning `price` on the previous line.

```
(
    uint80 roundID, 
    int price,
    uint startedAt,
    uint timeStamp,
    uint80 answeredInRound
) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
return price; // the `price` is returned, and the function doesn't execute after this line
return timeStamp; // this is ignored because of the early return on previous line
```

If you want to return multiple values, you can use this syntax:

```
// note the multiple datatypes in the `returns` block
function getThePriceAndTimestamp() public view returns (int, uint) {
    (
        uint80 roundID, 
        int price,
        uint startedAt,
        uint timeStamp,
        uint80 answeredInRound
    ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
    return (price, timeStamp); // here returning multiple values
}
```

Comment: Oh, btw, does the above mean the return statement can only be used once per function declared?

Comment: You can use multiple returns. It makes sense in a conditional return (example: `if(user.isActive == false) { return 0; } else { return user.score; }`) ... Just in your particular case the second would be **always** ignored.

Comment: @PetrHejda I think you meant to say `2^255` instead of `2^255-1` in the note about the Solidity v0.8 exception?

`2^255-1` is `type(int256).max`, and so it fits within `int256`.

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg Yes, that was my miscalculation. Thank you, I fixed in in the post.